# Is there any way to use dotenv with Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: continuous-integration, environment-variables, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

As the title says, is there any way to use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) with Bitbucket Pipelines for CI purposes, while still adding the (perhaps multiple) `(.stage).env` to .gitignore?

I know Pipeline supports [environment variables](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-794502608.html), and that they can be referenced [in bitbucket-pipelines.yml](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html), but I can't figure out how to use `dotenv` files instead, and vary which file to use based on i.e. branch patterns.

For example, I'd like commits to `develop` to use `.test.env` variables, while commits to `master` instead uses the variables from `.prod.env`.

Perhaps I'm going down the wrong path? Although other websites use examples of multiple `.env` files, [the library authors](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files) discourage that approach. I'm using Zeit Now for hosting, so I can't just SSH a `.env` file onto the server.

Any advice is very welcome :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a `base64` string out of your `.env` file. Then copy this string into your environment variables of your pipeline, see here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/environment-variables-794502608.html

For example, your content is now defined in `APP_ENV`, then you can use this line in your pipeline configuration file:

`echo $APP_ENV | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ./www/.env`

Now it is save because nobody knows your secrets in this file except your pipeline container itself.

This method could be used for all .env-files, also staging files. :)

Comment: I tried this but it creates an empty file. What am I missing, and how can I debug it?

Comment: Did you check if the env variable is set properly?

Answer (score 3):

Rename the files inside your develop pipelines:

```
mv .test.env .env
```

or in your master pipelines:

```
mv .prod.env .env
```

Comment: But that would still require the .[stage].env files to be committed to the repo, which I'd prefer not to :)